# Android bluetooth programming: Sending event/data from Bluetooth headset to Android Phone via bluetooth.

Tags: android, bluetooth

As part of one of my course project, i want to initiate/trigger my own android app through the bluetooth headset or any such bluetooth device by pressing the available button on them. I will press any specific button on my bluetooth headset and my application should be able to detect that button press event and start its execution automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html. You need to create a listening bluetooth server on you'r phone, read Connecting as a server and Working with Profiles.